# google analytics track clicks without supplying url

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I've been using Stack Overflow for years, but am posting for the first time for a hopefully simple jQuery solution I can't figure out.

I am operating a website, and would like to track outbound links. I've read and implemented https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1136920?hl=en. I am using wordpress, and it's super annoying to adjust every link, especially header links, so I would like to add a javascript/jquery script that captures click events on all links, and the links that that link links to.

Google Analytics says to use the following code in every html link tag:

```html
<a href="http://www.example.com" onclick="trackOutboundLink('http://www.example.com'); return false;">Check out example.com</a>
```

but I'd like to just write one simple jQuery function that is triggered by all clicks on any link on my website, and to fill the `trackOutboundLink("")` with whatever the link is. Is there a `$this.href()` or something I can use in this case?

Basically, I want to just have an event listener for all links, and log them like this:

`$( "a" ).click(function() {trackOutboundLink($this.a.href)});`

Sorry, I know my question is ill worded, and I'm a huge jQuery n00b, but don't know a better way to ask it... and, yes, I do want to log every link, even internal links. I don't care. I just want a super easy way to log links.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I think you want this `$(this).attr('href')`

Answer (score 0):

First you need a selector that selects all urls that are outbound. One of their traits is that they contain some form of protocol usually. Then you exclude all links that are pointing to your domain. Finally you use a simple click event to prevent the default behaviour of navigating, and instead execute the tracking code that will make the user navigate via a callback.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
  var domain = "example.com";
  $('a[href*=http]:not([href*=\'' + domain + '\'])').on('click', function (e) {
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    e.preventDefault();
    ga('send', 'event', 'outbound', 'click', url, {
       'transport': 'beacon',
       'hitCallback': function(){document.location = url;}
    });
  });
});
```